# Graph API encounter 400 failed to get drive in china

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-china

Before a day, the operation works fine.
https://microsoftgraph.chinacloudapi.cn/v1.0/users/{user_id}/drives

Suddenly, it keeps encounter this error:

> {
>   "error": {
>       "code": "BadRequest",
>       "message": "Unable to retrieve user's mysite URL.",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "d50647af-33c2-4503-a6c1-eb046173108c",
>         "date": "2018-04-03T08:33:58"
>       }
>     }
>   }

I have checked the subscription and APP permission in graph API, all permission is enabled

And I have tested another APP using the same graph API permission which works fine.

Do not know what going wrong here

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you checked the license status of subscription  ? If your onedrive license is expired it may cause this issue.

Comment: hi @WayneYang-MSFT: 
thanks for reply, I have checked the license status of subscription.
In fact, the most rest API requests are still working.
Now I am stresing to another app to reproduce this.